# Skewed thoughts

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does "skewed thoughts" mean ?

Is it related to being deviant or down or nervous or angry or paranoid or maniac?

In which situations do you say "I have skewed thoughts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many meanings of 'skewed' but then, in this context, I feel it means having distorted thoughts. It may happen that you cannot decide upon *one* thing and incline toward other.

I think depending on a context, it changes in its meaning. If you provide us with some more information, we may *even* find better word to describe the situation!